# I have an ajax call firing twice (jQuery) and have tried the solutions found here and nothing has worked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My ajax call goes and enters a record into a database (it's the first part of a form recording data) so I need it to return the id from the database entry.

Problem is, it's firing twice, so it's making 2 database entries each time.

I tried using a `$count` and `while($count>0)` in my php code to make sure that wasn't looping - and I didn't think it was, so the problem lies in my jQuery.

I tried putting the `preventDefault` on my submit button click function and that didn't work either.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#wpgstep1').one('click',function(){
        // validate form fields are all filled in

        var budget=$('#budget').val();
        if(budget=='')
        {
            $('#budgeterror').show();
        }

        var yellowpages=$('#ads-yellowpages').val();
        var flyers=$('#ads-flyers').val();
        var brochures=$('#ads-brochures').val();
        var radiotv=$('#ads-radiotv').val();
        var none=$('#ads-none').val();
        var other=$('ads-other').val();
        var otherstatement=$('ads-other-statement').val();
        var cust_id=$('#cust_id').val();

        if(other !='')
        {
            if(otherstatement==='')
            {

                $('#adsothererror').show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            otherin='0';
        }
        if(yellowpages==="on")
        {
            yellowpagesin='1';
        }
        else{
            yellowpagesin='0';
        }
        if(flyers==="on")
        {
            flyersin='1';
        }
        else
        {
            flyersin='0';
        }
        if(brochures==="on")
        {
            brochuresin='1'
        }
        else
        {
            brochuresin='0';
        }
        if(radiotv==="on")
        {
            radiotvin='1';
        }
        else
        {
            radiotvin='0';
        }
        if(none==="on")
        {
            nonein='1'
        }
        else
        {
            nonein='0';
        }
        var dataString='cust_id=' + cust_id + '&step=1&budget=' + budget + '&yellowpages='+yellowpagesin + '&flyers=' + flyersin + '&brochures='  + brochuresin + '&radiotv='+ radiotvin + '&none='+ nonein + '&other=' + otherstatement;

        $.ajax({
            type:  "POST",
            url:  "submitwpg.php",
            data:  dataString,
            dataType:'json',
            success:  function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                var i="";
                var p=eval (data);

                for (i in p)
                {
                    $('#wpgpart2').append('<input type=hidden name=wpgid value=' + p[i] + '>');
                }
                $('#wpgform1').hide();
                $('#wpgform2').show();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: I have posted an answer below but the question is ... are you double clicking the link/button ?

Comment: I'd comment out ajax call first and figured `does it fire twice?` question via `alert()` or `console.log()`. Then, when you know it fires once, the problem might just go away

Answer (score 1):

Make a global var

```
var form_submitting = false;
```

Above your ajax call

```
if(form_submitting == false){
    form_submitting = true;

    //your ajax call

}
```

In your success function of your ajax call

```
form_submitting = false;
```

Comment: I tried that and it is still firing it off twice. I can see it in my Firebug console and then it does the double entry into the database.  This is very puzzling...and frustrating.  It's acting like two events are being fired off, one right after the other.

Comment: @user2272153 if you implemented the code correctly above there is no way two submissions can be made, my only suggestion is to remove the `form_submitting = false;` from your success code so that the ajax can only ever fire once and go from there.

Comment: Even when I made the submit button NOT a submit button (I just made a div and styled it like a button with an ID to assign to a click event) it still fires it off twice.  I'm wondering what would happen if I remove the <form> tags entirely but I don't think that's the answer either.

Comment: Okay I had ignored the make it a GLOBAL variable....as soon as I did that, voila.  It's only submitting once!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your submit button is inside of a form, it may be possible that your ajax function is executing and then your form is posting regularly.  You could try turning your

```
<input type='submit' />
```

into

```
<button type='button' onclick='validateAndAjaxFunction(); return false;'></button>
```

Comment: If that works and you are doing all of your posting through ajax, you could just get rid of the form or the 'action' attribute inside of the form